# angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker not auto close on Date selection

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-bootstrap

I am using https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker datepicker. it is not auto closing the datepicker control..

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle my-toggle-select" id="dLabel1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
<div class="input-append">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar input-icon input-icon-highlight"></i>
    <label id="lblCheckOut" ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.homelabel | objectByKeyValFilter:'LblId':'lblCheckOut'">{{value.TextMessage}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtCheckOutDate" class="form-control" data-ng-model="CheckOutDate.date | date:'MMM d, EEE' " />
</div>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel1">
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="CheckOutDate.date" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" data-before-render="vm.beforeRender_CheckOutDate($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate,1);" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '.my-toggle-select' ,startView:'day', minView:'day'}"></datetimepicker>
</ul>
```

I could not find any property to auto close the angular bootstrap datepicker...

Comment: Can you look in the console and see if there are any messages when the page is loaded?
Do you have jQuery on the page?

Comment: This part of your configuration will handle the closing for you ONLY if bootstrap.js and jQuery are on the page: `dropdownSelector: '.my-toggle-select' `

Comment: @dale.lotts It's already have , but its angular application with bootstrap & jquery..

Comment: It looks like you may have copied the code from the readme - some of it was out-of-date - I updated readme to have current bootstrap 3 example.  Look at the demo page for more examples. Please create a jsbin, fiddle, or plunker that reproduces the problem if the other examples don't help.

Comment: OK Thank you @dale.lotts. I will check it out again. and get back to you if any issue persist..

Comment: @dale.lotts i found there was issue with dropdown class wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed by wrapping bootstrap class to given HTML..

```
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="dropdown-toggle my-toggle-select" id="dLabel1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
<div class="input-append">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar input-icon input-icon-highlight"></i>
    <label id="lblCheckOut" ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.homelabel | objectByKeyValFilter:'LblId':'lblCheckOut'">{{value.TextMessage}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtCheckOutDate" class="form-control" data-ng-model="CheckOutDate.date | date:'MMM d, EEE' " />
</div>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel1">
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="CheckOutDate.date" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" data-before-render="vm.beforeRender_CheckOutDate($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate,1);" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '.my-toggle-select' ,startView:'day', minView:'day'}"></datetimepicker>
</ul>
</div>
```

It's working correctly..

Thank you @Dale for your review and updates.